# How to get fifth value

Tags: r, split

```
data("iris")
len<-split(iris$Petal.Length,iris$Species)
len[5]
```

len data:

```
$setosa
 [1] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.6 1.4 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.3 1.4 1.7 1.5 1.7 1.5 1.0 1.7 1.9 1.6 1.6 1.5 1.4 1.6
[31] 1.6 1.5 1.5 1.4 1.5 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.6 1.9 1.4 1.6 1.4 1.5 1.4

$versicolor
 [1] 4.7 4.5 4.9 4.0 4.6 4.5 4.7 3.3 4.6 3.9 3.5 4.2 4.0 4.7 3.6 4.4 4.5 4.1 4.5 3.9 4.8 4.0 4.9 4.7 4.3 4.4 4.8 5.0 4.5 3.5
[31] 3.8 3.7 3.9 5.1 4.5 4.5 4.7 4.4 4.1 4.0 4.4 4.6 4.0 3.3 4.2 4.2 4.2 4.3 3.0 4.1

$virginica
 [1] 6.0 5.1 5.9 5.6 5.8 6.6 4.5 6.3 5.8 6.1 5.1 5.3 5.5 5.0 5.1 5.3 5.5 6.7 6.9 5.0 5.7 4.9 6.7 4.9 5.7 6.0 4.8 4.9 5.6 5.8
[31] 6.1 6.4 5.6 5.1 5.6 6.1 5.6 5.5 4.8 5.4 5.6 5.1 5.1 5.9 5.7 5.2 5.0 5.2 5.4 5.1

Error:NULL
```

Comment: What 5th value?  `sapply(len, '[', 5)` ?

Comment: Please be more concisely in order to get help from others, i don't think everyone knows what your problem is.

Comment: I want get 
$setosa 1.4
$versicolor 4.6
$virginica 5.8

Comment: THX! @akrun  it can work!  but I don't '[' mean?

Comment: It is `?Extract`.  or you can use anonymous function `sapply(len, function(x) x[5])`

Comment: Why are you reducing a perfectly fine data frame to something difficult when iris[5, ] is all you need to get to the fifth value of all your columns?

Answer (score 1):

We need to loop through the `list` (`lapply`- returns a `list`, while `sapply` returns a `vector`) and get the 5th element

```
sapply(len, '[', 5)
#setosa versicolor  virginica 
#   1.4        4.6        5.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use purrr's map function within the tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)
split(iris$Petal.Length,iris$Species) %>% map(5)
$setosa
[1] 1.4

$versicolor
[1] 4.6

$virginica
[1] 5.8
```